# react-native-wagmi-charts doesnt responds on touch on android

Tags: android, ios, react-native, graph, expo

library is https://github.com/rainbow-me/react-native-animated-charts

works on IOS but not on android

using expo-cli

library versions

```
"react-native-wagmi-charts": "^2.1.0",
"react-native-reanimated": "^2.4.1",
```

Answer (score 2):

This solution worked for me on Expo

https://github.com/coinjar/react-native-wagmi-charts/issues/73#issuecomment-1055333633

Example:

```
import { gestureHandlerRootHOC } from "react-native-gesture-handler";

const Chart = gestureHandlerRootHOC(() => (
    <View>
      {/* LineChart here */}
    </View>
));

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Chart />
    </View>
  );
}
```

or

```
import { GestureHandlerRootView } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <GestureHandlerRootView>
      <Chart />
    </GestureHandlerRootView>
  );
}
```